# Meteor collection findOne returning undefined when called in callback

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to find().fetch() in a Meteor Collection, however when I call this code within a Callback (or in the directly in the console, it returns []).

```
MyClass = class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        this.worker = null;
        this._init();

        console.log(Site.MyCollection.find().fetch()); //Logs the array of documents
    }

    _init() {
        this.worker = new Worker('my-web-worker.js');
        this.worker.addEventListener('message', this._onMessage, false);

        this.worker.postMessage({ cmd: 'start', data: Site.MyCollection.find().fetch() }); //Works fine, the Web Worker receives the array of documents as expected

    }


    _onMessage(e) {
        console.log(Site.MyCollection.find().fetch()); //Logs []
    }
}
```

There isn't anywhere where I'm removing any documents from the collection, so I'm unsure if this is a security feature, or if somehow the collections are being wiped after being created.

To create the (dummy) collection, I'm doing this (on the client and server)

```
Site.MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("my-collection");

Site.MyCollection.remove();

let docs = [
  {name:"One", data : ["a", "b", "c"}},
  {name:"Two", data : ["e", "f", "g"}},
  {name:"Three", data : ["h", "i", "j"}},
  {name:"Four", data : ["k", "l", "m"}}   
];

_.each(docs, function(doc){
  Site.MyCollection.insert(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaah turns out I'm an idiot, I'd removed the autopublish package. So

```
$meteor add autopublish
```

and then restarting the app fixed it.